# Trying to transfer BTC from Coinbase to Binance, commission 13 USD?

Tags: transaction-fees, network, coinbase.com

So basically I bought the equivalent of 100EUR in BTC with CoinBase (they took 3 EUR for this operation)

Now I would like to buy other currencies with binance, but if I try to send my BTC to my Binance BTC address it says the network fee are 13 USD.

Are them really so high? Is there something else that i could do?

Comment: Note that it's important to keep straight the distinction between a *commission* (paid to an exchange for a trade between BTC and EUR/USD/...), and *transaction/network fees* (paid to miners for a transaction which moves BTC from one address to another).

Comment: I have solved it by transfering with GDAX, no fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see current Bitcoin transaction fees at https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/.  Right now it is suggesting a fee of about BTC 0.001 which is about USD 13, so that's about right.  Note that transaction fees don't depend on the amount transacted; you'd pay the same fee of about USD 13 whether you were sending the equivalent of USD 100 or USD 100,000.

A few weeks ago, the fees were 2-3 times higher than they are now.  This is something you have to take into account when thinking about trading and moving Bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

You can pay a lower fee but this will risk it being stuck in the mempool forever—-not an advisable option.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to convert your Bitcoin to ether and transfer that to binance especially if the plan is to buy alt coins. If you want to keep it as btc than yes you have to pay the fee which is actually lower than it has been over the last month or two.